# Does installation of CustomRom chage the partition

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, custom-roms, stock-android, stock-rom

I have some basic question abt customROM

1.When you install customROM, does it change/recreate the partitions in previous ROM   stockROM/Custom) or it just installs the ROM in the  existing partitions (like windows)

2.What is ROMSlot, is it someting like MBR in windows ?

3.Is there any customROM that will unlock the bootloader for me and install itself.

4.Does cynogenMod works in ANY DEVICE  (i.e. Chinese )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, flashing ROM will not change your partition table.
2. No, flashing ROM won't unlock your bootloader (I think that you'll, in fact, need to be using unlocked bootloader to flash a ROM)
3. CyanogenMod is made for each device separately. If it's available for your device, you can install it. Go to their website to see if there's an official or unofficial port of CyanogenMod for your device.

Comment: thnx but cynogenmod claims that it will unlock the bootloader for you. My data partition got corrupt,so internal storage shows 0.0B, hence no app can be installed, I thought maybe flashing a custom ROM will fix it.

Comment: @Tanvir while installing custom ROM doesn't change the size of your partitions, it does wipe (delete their content) them, so installing a custom ROM might just fix the issue you're having with your phone (The issue may be in the software itself, maybe it's not really a corrupted partition). But first of all, check your partition table with help of [this thread](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5232/how-can-i-view-the-android-internal-partition-table) , so you know what you're dealing with.

Comment: thnx,I checked the partition through linux shell n found that the data partition shows NO INFO, something's gone wrong? Also the shutdown command resets the device.. sigh!!

Comment: @Tanvir well, in that case, you should try to repartition the table (make sure you follow a good tutorial on this). It seems already broken, so I doubt that you can make it any worse by repartitioning.

Comment: yup, thats why I didnt dare ..though I tried once but command didnt run... shows some error.. there's nothing to do .. :(

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović  please help me with this issue http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106256/how-to-unbrick-sony-xperia-c2305