# How to find out which file system is used by my device?

Tags: file-system

How do I find out which file system is used by my device's /system, /data and other partitions?

Comment: Related question: [How can I view the Android internal partition table?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5232/94084)

Answer (score 8):

[DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) displays this information (among other things) when you select a partition to view its details. Works with the internal partitions on my Nexus 5, but should also support external SD cards and the like:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: it doesn't tell me what filesystem `/sdcard` is

Comment: It says `sdcardfs` even though the file system actually is `exFAT`.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, one can use a Terminal Emulator app which requires no usage of **adb**.

1. Download a Terminal Emulator of your choice from Play Store [here](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=terminal&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiCgoIdGVybWluYWx6AhgAigECCAE%3D:S:ANO1ljJwzi8).
2. Open that app and issue the command `mount`. You can also use the command `df` to ascertain the partitions to be looked in the former output.
3. An alternative for mount is `blkid` command which shows a much better output for our need.

Note:- **3.** requires **ROOT** access while the other steps can work without it.

Comment: `df` doesn't show me the file system type, only the path in `/mnt` (not the mount point), two numbers (probably total and used bytes), percentage (probably of used storage) and another path (still not the mount point).

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
adb shell mount
```

to find out which file system is used by all the partitions of your device. You need to have adb installed, of course, for this to work. You can install adb by using (Windows only)[Minimal ADB and Fastboot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790), or you can install full android sdk, if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for traveling with... oops :) Yogesh: the linked XDA thread only works for Windows. See our question [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) for a more universal solution (supporting Linux and Mac as well). Or [minimal_adb_fastboot](https://github.com/simmac/minimal_adb_fastboot) with support for Mac (plus experimental Linux support).

Comment: Adb work also on google chrome in linux distributions like ubuntu, I have installed it and try it and work perfectly, so, my advice for those who know only windows, stop saying anything against linux distributions...