# Cannot mount mtdblock partition

Tags: adb, shell, mount, partitions

I'm trying to mount the boot partition of a tablet with MTD partitions. This is the output of `cat /proc/mtd`:

```
root@android:/ # cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00400000 00004000 "misc"
mtd1: 00c00000 00004000 "kernel"
mtd2: 00c00000 00004000 "boot"
mtd3: 02000000 00004000 "recovery"
mtd4: 04000000 00004000 "backup"
mtd5: 08000000 00004000 "cache"
mtd6: 40000000 00004000 "userdata"
mtd7: 00400000 00004000 "kpanic"
mtd8: 20000000 00004000 "system"
mtd9: 169400000 00004000 "user"
```

So, I make `/mnt/test`folder then run:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/block/mtdblock2 /mnt/test
```

And I get:

```
mount: Invalid argument
```

Same error with `ext4`. I tried `yaffs2` and I got:

```
mount: No such device
```

This is how it looks with [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo):

[image]

How can I mount this partition?

Comment: Related: [How to find out which file system is used by my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/105077/16575)