# Getting /sbin/sh: parted: not found error

Tags: adb, twrp, custom-roms, lineageos

So I am trying to resize my system partition on my Huawei P10 because the ROM I want to use is bigger than the current partition. I pushed gdisk and parted with ADB, but for some reason I can't run it in shell even though it's clearly there. See image attached
[image]

EDIT: I just had to copy the file into sbin, but now I get a permission denied error

Comment: Seems like Android is the first Linux system you are working with. On Linux files can only be executed if they have the eXecutable bit set your the own, the owner-group or other. Use `chmod` to set.

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: [How to run "parted" command in terminal emulator on my android smartphone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/191253/44325)