# How to get the size of the “super” partition on the device?

Tags: rooting, partitions

[lpmake](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/partition_tools/README.md) requires to get the size of the “super” partition on the device:

> -d,--device-size - The size of the “super” partition on the device. It must match exactly, and it must be evenly divisible by the sector size (512 bytes).

*How can I obtain it?*

Using adb, I was able to run  `ls -la /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name` and see

> `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 2022-06-13 23:32 super -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p34`

and then using termux, as root, I obtained:

> `blockdev --getsz /dev/block/mmcblk0p34`
> `8388608`

but since the original firmware's `system.img` file is 3.2 GiB (3,435,159,228 > 8,388,608), this seems quite unlikely.

What am I missing?
I am aware of [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5232/188657), but it did not helped.

The scatter file reads

```
- partition_index: SYS35
  partition_name: super
  file_name: super.img
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x23800000
  physical_start_addr: 0x23800000
  partition_size: 0x100000000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  is_upgradable: true
  empty_boot_needed: false
  reserve: 0x00
```

and `0x10000000` is `268435456` (268,435,456), but that's still not enough?

I see another number using fastboot...

```
fastboot getvar partition-size:super
partition-size:super: 100000000
finished. total time: 0.003s
```

and

```
echo "ibase=16; 100000000"|bc
4294967296
```

This one could be valid, since 4,294,967,296 > 3,435,159,228.

Comment: `blockdev --getsize64` 8388608 (blocks) x 512 (block size) = 4294967296 = 0x100000000 (not sure where you got 0x10000000 its not mentioned in scatter file)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had forgotten a `0` in my conversion…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, all three sources are in agreement when you know how to read it:

## Scatter

> partition_size: 0x100000000

`0x100000000` = `4,294,967,296` (I had forgotten a `0` in my question)

## blockdev

> `blockdev --getsz /dev/block/mmcblk0p34`

`8388608` = `8388608` (blocks) x `512` (block size) = `4,294,967,296` (Thanks alecxs!)

## fastboot

> `fastboot getvar partition-size:super`

Gives `0x100000000` = `0x100000000` = `4,294,967,296`