# lpmake complaining about not having enough space

Tags: partitions

I am trying, following [this tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/editing-system-img-inside-super-img-and-flashing-our-modifications.4196625/), to re-package a `super.img` file, but am confused by lpmake.

I am trying to package the following 3 images:

| partition | size |
| --- | --- |
| lineage-18.1-20220511-UNOFFICIAL-arm64_avS.img | 2035568640 |
| vendor.img | 312594432 |
| product.img | 1945939968 |
| *total* | 4294103040 |

using the command

```
lpbinary/binary/lpmake \
    --metadata-size 65536 --metadata-slots 1 --device super:4294103040 \
    --group main:4294103040 --partition system:readonly:2035568640:main \
    --image system=./lineage-18.1-20220511-UNOFFICIAL-arm64_avS.img \
    --partition vendor:readonly:312594432:main --image vendor=./vendor.img \
    --partition product:readonly:1945939968:main --image product=./product.img \
    --sparse --output ./super.new.img
```

and I get back:

```
lpmake I 06-14 05:43:50  7411  7411 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition system will resize from 0 bytes to 2035568640 bytes
lpmake I 06-14 05:43:50  7411  7411 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition vendor will resize from 0 bytes to 312594432 bytes
lpmake E 06-14 05:43:50  7411  7411 builder.cpp:698] [liblp]Not enough free space to expand partition: product
Not enough space on device for partition product with size 1945939968
```

[I don't know the size of my super partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247106/188657), so I simply set `--device super:4294103040`, thinking that the sum of the images should hold on a partition of the same size.

Why is this not working? Does the partition needs to be bigger than the image? If yes, by which factor?

Comment: super = group main + metadata-size. sure you want the readonly flag?

Comment: @alecxs a. How do you know the metadata-size? b. I am not sure I want the `readonly` flag. How can I decide?

Comment: lineageos comes without google bloat. some people want install OpenGApps or microG to get google play services functional, therefore system must mounted rw

Comment: @alecxs Thanks a lot, I was not aware of this. In my case (where I don't want to install OpenGApps or microG), I believe it does not change anything, but I am glad I know the reason why now.